# No Paypal IPN response on mobile deveice

Tags: php, mobile, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'am working on shoping cart, everything is ok. My problem is with IPN response on mobile deveice. on windows IPN sending back post variables, just fine but when I acces to website from mobile and making payment there, IPN is just returning empty post. I followed every step on paypal developer site and there is not much information about this issue on internet.

I'am using this IPN code from GitHup https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

I have set up IPN Notifications on PayPal. 
I have notify_url in my form. 
On the other side those payments makes from mobile, registered on paypal as payment status completed and ipn history is ok.

Do you have any ide about what problem is?

here is the my test website

http://gurweb.se/portfolioShowCase/online_pizza/
login with abc@hotmail.com and pass 123, this will make easy to pass through contact form.

Try it with windows browser and mobile to understand what i mean.

I'am testing it on Iphone6.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Hello, wondering if you found an answer? I am having the same issue but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: The solution I found is work around the problem. There is no solution for mobilephone on PayPal. If you use IPN code from GitHub there is a IPN log file. When payments makes from mobile PayPal register it as normal in history and payment completed and the log file. So got the code from log file put them in array, explode them and than register in db as mobile payment. If you check your log file with mobile payment, you will understand better what I mean. If you find better solution please let me know :)